# Using a <a href> inside a gridview

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have anchor tag inside a gridview which im using javascript onclick to popup a new window. It all work the way as expected except that when the window popups if make the parent page do an autopostback. I have researched this but cant find why this is happening or how to fix it. Here is my code below, first is my grid and second is the javacsript function.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" BackColor="White" 
        BorderColor="#003366" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
        GridLines="Vertical"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Small">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#D9ECFF" BorderColor="#003366" />
        <Columns>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SELECT">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="#" onclick="clickMe('<%# Eval("ICAO") %>')" target="_top">Test</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ICAO" HeaderText="ICAO" SortExpression="ICAO" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IATA" HeaderText="IATA" SortExpression="IATA" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="AIRPORT_NAME" HeaderText="AIRPORT NAME" SortExpression="AIRPORT_NAME" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CITY" HeaderText="CITY" SortExpression="CITY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="COUNTRY" HeaderText="COUNTRY" SortExpression="COUNTRY" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="REVISED_DATE" HeaderText="REVISED DATE" SortExpression="REVISED_DATE" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="EMAIL_DATE" HeaderText="EMAIL DATE" SortExpression="EMAIL_DATE" />          
        </Columns>

        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#465c71" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" 
            Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next" Position="Top" 
            PreviousPageText="Previous" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" ForeColor="#465c71" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F4F4FD" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#5A4C9D" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D8D8F0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#3E3277" />

    </asp:GridView>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function clickMe(icao) {
        targetUrl = "login.aspx?icao=" + icao
        window.open(targetUrl, 'Rep_Search', 'toolbar=no, directories=no,    
        location=no,status=yes, menubar=no, resizable=no, scrollbars=yes, height=300, 
       width=400'); return false;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "onclick" attribute should say `onclick='return clickMe( ... )'`. Your handler is returning `false`, but that code in the attribute is basically the **real** handler, and it doesn't have a `return` at all.

Also, just as some advice, it's kind-of a good idea to post as little code as possible. It makes it easier for people to scan the question and look for simple issues. Of course, narrowing down the code *too* much is not good, because it's so easy to make mistaken assumptions about what's causing your problems.